# Geolocation distance queries in Neo4j

Tags: .net, neo4j, geolocation, geospatial, neo4jclient

I was looking at geolocation queries in Neo4j but I assume there is no built in support for this like there is in Elasticsearch for example. I have seen [neo4j-contrib spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) but I can see that it is highly Java based whereas I will talk to Neo4j from .NET. There seems to be a server plugin for that but I am not sure as I haven't been able to find any samples on that.

So, I am more for writing the geolocation query myself through [Mathematical functions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-mathematical.html) but I am not sure how the performance would be for high volume data sets.

What is the preferred way to handle this type of queries in Neo4j? For example, answering the below question:

> Who are my friends which liked the same products as I did and live within my 10km radius?

Answer (score 3):

Once installed, the spatial extension includes an index provider that can be referenced from Cypher. So your question could be answered with a query like this:

```
START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[46.9163, -114.0905, 10.0]')
MATCH (me:Person {name: "Bob"})-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(n)
MATCH (n)-[:LIKED]->(p:Product)<-[:LIKED]-(me)
RETURN n
```

There is a good series of blog posts on this [here](http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/01/31/neo4j-spatial-part-1/) and [here](http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/02/11/neo4j-spatial-part-2/).